# Data not binded to scope variables from input text fileds

Tags: angularjs

This is my HTML markup:

```
<form name="quotaForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">username:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="nameFiled"
               ng-model="username" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateQuota()">Update</button>
</form>
```

This is the code in controller:

```
$scope.updateQuota=function(){
alert($scope.username);// I am getting null data even if I entered data in field 
}
```

Comment: Fiddle everything working fine http://jsfiddle.net/wawbkLz2/ I guess problem is somewhere else in your code provide us complete code :-)

Comment: did you find anything else ?

Comment: @squiroid you are right, she missed something else

Comment: I have cheked the jsfiddle which you have shared, in this its working fine. But unable to figure out the problem in my code.

Comment: This type of data binding issue happened long back, At that time I have used $scope.quotaForm.nameFiled.$modelValue to get the data.

Comment: @Lakshmi could you please share your more code so that we can help you out with it..

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't see all your code here, I can make a pretty safe bet that this is a scoping issue. If you are using a directive in your view that is creating a new scope, like ng-if, than you will need to reference the parent. ng-model="$parent.username" in the view will fix this:

```
<form name="quotaForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">username:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="nameFiled" ng-model="$parent.username" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateQuota()">Update</button>
</form>
```

But like I said this is only a guess.

Comment: How can you use $parent here?

Comment: $parent would then reference the controller scope variables, if this HTML is nested in a newly created scope. Right? I could be wrong.

Comment: yeah..you could be right if it is nested..but the questioner doesn't gave any code..

Comment: Yes, hence the reason my answer begins with "Even though I don't see all your code here, I can make a pretty safe bet that" and ends with "But like I said this is only a guess." :). I figure this likely the cause of the issue because it has cause me a world of hurt in the past.